# Specific key in map causes an access violation error, only shows up without gdb

Tags: c++, stl

I am using a map to store bitmap coordinates for characters, to use when rendering characters from a sprite sheet.
The coordinates map is defined as

```
typedef std::array<double,4> Coordinates;
typedef std::unordered_map<char, Coordinates> CharacterMapping;
```

I supply the coordinates one by one, like so

```
CharacterMapping *charMap = new CharacterMapping();
(*charMap)['a'][0] = 0; (*charMap)['a'][1] = 0; (*charMap)['a'][2] = 8; (*charMap)['a'][3] = 8;
(*charMap)['b'][0] = 8; (*charMap)['b'][1] = 0; (*charMap)['b'][2] = 16; (*charMap)['b'][3] = 8;
(*charMap)['c'][0] = 16; (*charMap)['c'][1] = 0; (*charMap)['c'][2] = 24; (*charMap)['c'][3] = 8;
(*charMap)['d'][0] = 24; (*charMap)['d'][1] = 0; (*charMap)['d'][2] = 32; (*charMap)['d'][3] = 8;
// and so on, including numbers and some other symbols...
(*charMap)['.'][0] = 49; (*charMap)['.'][1] = 32; (*charMap)['.'][2] = 55; (*charMap)['.'][3] = 40;
(*charMap)[' '][0] = 57; (*charMap)[' '][1] = 32; (*charMap)[' '][2] = 63; (*charMap)[' '][3] = 40;
(*charMap)[','][0] = 1; (*charMap)[','][1] = 40; (*charMap)[','][2] = 7; (*charMap)[','][3] = 48;
```

and then the coordinates are supplied to the classes I created, (Drawable is a container class with a pointer to a shape object that represents a drawable object, Shape is an abstract class that represents graphical shapes, SpriteText is a subclass of shape)

```
SpriteText* spriteTextShape = new SpriteText(Vector(100,700), // position
            ltrTex, // the bitmap
            *charMap, // the map
            "hello world\nalso you\n1. it is ok, dont worry!\n2. what?"); // some text
Drawable *drw = new Drawable(world, // a container of all objects
            spriteTextShape); // the shape
```

This works fine and well as long as i omit the coordinates for the space character or run the program under gdb.
If the program is simply run, it crashes with a -1073741819 access violation error code on the drawable constructor line. (identified by printing each line in console, does not enter the constructor itself).

Deleting the line, replacing the ' ' with any other character (like '\') or just running it under gdb seem to solve it. Why would a change of key value affect or cause access violation error when calling a completely separate class constructor? How come it doesn't show up when using gdb?

The ctors:

```
SpriteText::SpriteText(const Vector& position, Graphics::Texture* const texture,
                    const CharacterMapping& coordinates, const std::string& text) :
        Shape(position) {
    _charDrawer = new CharSprite(position, Vector(1,1), texture, coordinates, 'c');
    _text_info.line_info_r = NULL;
    setText(text);
}
CharSprite::CharSprite(const Vector& position, const Vector& dimensions,
    Texture* const texture, const CharacterMapping& coordinates,
    const char& character):
    Sprite(position,dimensions,texture){
    setSpriteCoordinates(coordinates);
    setCurrentCharacter(character);
}
Drawable::Drawable(World* world, Shape* shape):
    GameObject(world){
    setWorld(world);
    _shape = shape;
    _drawableFlags = Drawable::Flags::BOUND_BY_WORLD;
}
```

Windows xp, mingw and g++.

Comment: Why all those `new`s? Isn't life already hard enough without them?

Comment: On spritetext it semms necessary, since Shape is abstract. on CharacterMapping it was mainly for testing purposes and using a non pointer initialized CharacterMapping resulted in the same result. Drawable adds itself to the world it is given as constructor argument, and without being new'd it will be delete'd when exiting the function (this is not the rendering loop so it would be bad).

Comment: What switches are you compiling with? Try compiling with `-O0 -ggdb -fno-omit-frame-pointers -Wall -Werror -fno-strict-aliasing` and see if you don't still see it under gdb.

Comment: Also, please show (at least) the fingerprint for the SpriteText and Drawable ctors.

Comment: @kfsone Added the ctors. I used `-g -std=gnu++0x -Wall`. Using the new switches (minus `-Werror`, had several -Wunused-variable errors) provided the same results, no error in gdb, error in plain run.